# Where can I visit the mussel grow locations in Rías Baixas, Galicia, Spain?

Tags: spain, tours, ecotourism

I would like to visit by boat where the mussels are grown in Rías Baixas. I have searched but I can only find boat trips where you hear the story and eat mussels. I would actually like to visit the place and see the ropes with mussels. I know it's possible but I don't know the company that does this or even the area where/city to look it up.

If it's around Vigo it would be a plus.

Comment: There are many punts (batea in Spanish) around Galicia. They are mostly situated on the estuary because it is a more protected part of the sea and when fishermen need to do "maintenance" fishermen need to do "maintenance" on then and in case of a storm they are more protected. There are punts all over galician estuaries (Rias Baixaxs: Ria de Vigo, Riga de Pontevedra, Ria de Arosa, Ria de Muros)

Answer (score 7):

There are many punts ("batea" in Spanish) around Galicia.

They are mostly situated on the estuary ("ría" in Spanish) because it is a more protected part of the sea and fishermen need to do "maintenance" or collect the product safely. 
[image]
There are punts all over Galician estuaries (Rías Baixas: Ría de Vigo, Ría de Pontevedra, Ría de Arosa, Ría de Muros).

I am not sure you can get on top of the punt (where mussels grow) since **it is dangerous to fall** from it the closest you can get is to the side.

[image]

Here is a link with images and [tours](http://crucerosangel.com/galeria/). It is not near Vigo but is not far away.

Answer (score 4):

The heart of Rias Bajas is actually the ria of Pontevedra. I am quoting the tourist office in Vigo.

I was focusing on Vigo ria, which has many boats, but mainly going to Cies.

Around Pontevedra ria there are many cities with boats that do the mussels route. In Vigo there is only one that does it mainly on Sundays. So the offer is very scarce and it is often complete.

Around Pontevedra you can easily find a boat without reservation. Look at locations like Ogroove. As an example I called to a company and they were quite surprised when I asked to reserve.

Extra tip: I ended up doing a 1h15 cruise. Try to find one with at least half an hour more. It was really nice but you feel you needed more time to enjoy. Specially with the wine and the mussels served on board.

Comment: @ nsn Can you please accept an answer (your own is as acceptable as any other.)

Comment: @Willeke I usually like to wait a bit longer to see if any other, better, answers arise.

Comment: @ nsn please do not wait too long, I know many of your questions that did not got accepted answers for over a year, (and some never got one yet after a few years.)

Comment: @Willeke is it mandatory? I mean, many times there isn't "the answer". All of them complement each other. I never got the idea that having an accepted answer was something absolutly needed.

Comment: @ nsn, it is not mandatory, but it is a feature of the site to have accepted answers and it gives a good feeling for those have done some (or even quite a bit) of hard work for you. And you do run the risk that some of the more experienced users stop answering your questions, as you can not be bothered to accept an answer.

Comment: @Willeke that was never my intention. It's not that hard to accept an answer and you even get rewarded with a couple of points for it.  I try to be strict in what I accept, and usually try accept truly canonical answers. It's not impossible that I might have left one or other behind but not on purpose.